# Read XML in SSMS

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, openxml, sql-server-openxml, openxml-table

I'm trying to produce an output that would give me both long-descriptions, i.e. one in German and one in English.  It can be two records with 1 [long-description] column and one [lang] column, or 1 record with both [long-description-de] and [long-description-en] columns.  So far I have found 2 methods, not sure which is better but I'm still not able to produce the exact output with either of them:

```
-- XML
DECLARE @idoc INT, @doc NVARCHAR(max);   
SET @doc ='  
<enfinity>
  <offer sku="123456">
    <sku>123456</sku>
    <long-description xml:lang="de-DE">German</long-description>
    <long-description xml:lang="en-US">English</long-description>
  </offer>
</enfinity>
';   
  


-- Method 1 
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc;   

SELECT *  
FROM   OPENXML (@idoc, '/enfinity/offer/long-description')   
WITH(               sku   int    '../sku',
               [long-description]      nvarchar(max)         '../long-description',
               lang         nvarchar(max)         '../@lang');
               


-- Method 2
DECLARE @T XML
SET @T = @doc

SELECT Y.ID.value('@sku', 'nvarchar(max)') as [sku],
        Y.ID.value('@long-description', 'nvarchar(max)') as [long-description-de],
        Y.ID.value('@long-description', 'nvarchar(max)') as [long-description-en]
FROM @T.nodes('/enfinity/offer') as Y(ID)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

Important points:

- It is better to use XML data type instead of `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.
- It is better not to use Microsoft proprietary `OPENXML()`. It was made for the now obsolete SQL  Server 2000.
- It is better to use XQuery methods `.nodes()` and `.value()`. They
  are available starting from MS SQL Server 2005 onwards.
- It is important to distinguish XML element vs. attributes. That's why your both attempts didn't work.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @doc XML = 
N'<enfinity>
  <offer sku="123456">
    <sku>123456</sku>
    <long-description xml:lang="de-DE">German</long-description>
    <long-description xml:lang="en-US">English</long-description>
  </offer>
</enfinity>';

SELECT c.value('@sku', 'nvarchar(max)') as [sku]
    , c.value('(long-description[@xml:lang="de-DE"]/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as [long-description-de]
    , c.value('(long-description[@xml:lang="en-US"]/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as [long-description-en]
FROM @doc.nodes('/enfinity/offer') as t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  sku   | long-description-de | long-description-en |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 123456 | German              | English             |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: That's perfect thank you.  Just out of curiosity what happens if I don't know what the lang will be?  So for some data it might have
    <long-description xml:lang="zh-hk">Cantonese</long-description>
for example, is there a way to code it so we don't hardcode all the languages?

Comment: You can add additional languages as columns, just their values will be NULLs.

Comment: Sorry should have been more clear although I think I just answered my own question.  I was hoping for something more eloquent like rather than hardcoding all possible languages, search for what languages are available first and only display them as columns.  But I suspect that will only be possible with dynamic T-SQL to build up the query.

Comment: on 2nd thought, is it possible to produce an output like this instead so I can dynamically pivot my result?
`
+--------+------------------+---------+
|  sku   | long-description |   lang  |
+--------+------------------+---------+
| 123456 | German           |  de-DE  |
+--------+------------------+---------+
| 123456 | English          |  en-US  |
+--------+------------------+---------+
`

Comment: Please ask a new question for the 2nd output, and I will gladly help you.

Comment: no probs, I was just curious as it's not needed anyway, I have however just raised another question as the xml is more complicated:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69167251/pivot-complex-xml-using-xquery